# Finding shortest path in the dynamic graph

Tags: graph, path

Here is my problem: I have a directed weighted graph with a substantial amount of vertices (few thousands), no cycles, in fact, it includes a starting node, a final node and a grid (m*n) between them, where edges can be directed from the left to the right only.
The weights of the edges depend on the path in which they are included (for example, if the path includes v.15, then the weights of several edges change).

I tried to get all possible paths and then calculate their final sum post factum, but that turned out to be very inefficient method due to the number of paths. Is there an effective method which allows to find shortest paths in these kind of graphs? Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain better your problem? It's not clear to me how is the weight of each edge calculated... If it depends on the length of a path, what if an edge is shared between two paths?

Comment: Thanks for your anwser. In fact, my problem is scheduling of the different TV shows. Let's imagine that I have three different TV shows (Show1, Show2, Show3) and 3 available times of their beginning (19:00, 20:00, 21:00). Each vertex represents the beginning of specific show at specific time. For example, [1,1] is the Show1 at 19:00, [3,3] is Show3 at 21:00. If Show1 length is less than or equal to 2 hours than we can connect these two vertices with an edge. Its weight is an anticipated TV audience. I hope, it was clear enough.